# find indices using for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I should estimate the effect of B fields on particle deflection using F=V.B force.

I have a 2D mesh with nx and ny which show the number of points in each direction.B is the magnetic field which is a 2D mesh arrays (with dimension nx.ny= 1600.900= 1440000) and V is the velocity of particles and is a 1D array (with dimension 431605462).  I also have two 1D arrays (with the same dimension as the V array) which show the X and y coordinates of each particles. I called them  'grid_pro_x ' and 'grid_pro_y'.

Since V is a 1D array and B is a 2D array I can not directly multiply V with B. To solve this issue I created a 2D zero array for the V and using 2 for loops I find particles which stand in each cell of the mesh. I consider the average velocity of all particles as a velocity component of each cell. because of the large dimensionality of the mesh, if I keep the original dimension, the code needs several days to complete the V array since it needs to be repeated 1440000 times. 
As a solution, I compressed V with an optional variable called 'divider'. If I use divider = 10 I guess the code needs 2 days to be finished and if I use divider = 100 the code will be finished in half an hour but now the precision of the results reduces significantly.  you can see the code in the following.

```
nx,ny= 1600, 900

xmin = -30.0e-6       
xmax =  50.0e-6   

ymin = -45.0e-6    
ymax = 45.0e-6 

#### create a 2D  velocity array

divider = 100
m_p= 1.6726219e-27   #  (kg unit)  proton mass

nx_new = nx/divider
ny_new = ny/divider 

Vx = np.zeros((ny_new, nx_new))
Vy = np.zeros((ny_new, nx_new))

res_x = (xmax - xmin)/nx_new   # resolution in x direction
res_y = (ymax - ymin)/ny_new   # resolution in y direction

  #   Find corresponding indices 

  for i in range( 0,ny_new ):                  
     for j in range(  0,nx_new):                

        xx = i*res_x    
        yy = j*res_y 

  ##### all particles with different Px confined in a specific cell

        Px_pro_lim = Px_pro[(grid_pro_x >=  xx ) & (grid_pro_x < xx+res_x ) & (grid_pro_y >=  yy ) & (grid_pro_y < yy+res_y ) ] 

        Vx[i,j] = np.mean(Px_pro_lim)/m_p 
  #print 'Vx[i,j]= ' ,Vx[i,j]
```

Do you have any recommendation for improving the efficiency of the code or do you have any other algorithms for finding a 2D array for the V parameter?

cheers

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place

Comment: thanks  I will ask there

Comment: @Will, this code isn't complete enough for CodeReview.  Pleaae don't recommend CR unless you are active on that board

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as **too broad** for this site; While its on-topicness for CR is being evaluated, it has been [cross-posted on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221340/120114)

Comment: The obvious question from a `numpy` perspective is, can we replace the `i,j` loops with whole-array operations.  That is, move the iteration to compiled code.  But without a working copy-n-paste example (not too large) i have no interest in tackling that question.  The text mentions arrays `V` and `B`, but the code has variables like `Px_pro` and `grid_pro_x`.  Indenting is off as well.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for replying. As I explained   'grid_pro_x ' and 'grid_pro_y' are two 1D arrays (with the same dimension as the V array) which show the x and y coordinates of each particles. The code works well but you just need to add  three 1D arrays which are   'grid_pro_x ' and 'grid_pro_y'  and 'Vx'. We should change 'Vx' to a 2D array using the coordinates . the coordinates of 'Vx' are restored in  'grid_pro_x ' and 'grid_pro_y'